# Why start project not executing dependent project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I have created a new C++ solution (Test.sln) to get `static lib` file which I need to `add in my main solution (Main.sln)`.
I have added the `Test.lib` in `debug folder` of `Main.sln`. Provided all the paths (`like include and .lib`).
But when building/running the project `Main.sln` is not building/executing `Test.sln or Test.lib`.

Please help where am I going wrong?
I am using `visual studio 2010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one single solution, containing two projects (the "main" project and the "test" project). Make the "main" project depend on the "test" project. When you build the "main" project the "test" project will be built automatically.

Set the projects properties of the "main" project to link with the library in the "test" project, no need to copy files.

Comment: I had a project earlier. Now I have created another project. I have added the project inot my new project. And provided `additional dependancy(Test.lib)`.  So here the main.sln should run `Test.sln/lib` but it is not happening